# Looping through div between two h3 classes

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping with beautifulsoup and py through an html that has the following structure:

```
<div>
    <div class="type__icon"> ... </div>
    <h2 class="type__heading"> ... </h2>
    <div class="type__description"> ... </div>
    <h3 class="type__purpose-heading"> ... </h3>
    <div class="type__grid"> ...
        <div class="type__grid-icon"> ... </div>
        <div class="type__grid-content"> ... </div>
            <h4 class="type__category-heading"> ... </h4>
            <ul class="type__category-items"> ... </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="type__grid"> ...</div>
    <div class="type__grid"> ...</div>
    <div class="type__grid"> ...</div>
    <div class="type__grid"> ...</div>
    <h3 class="type__purpose-heading"> ... </h3>
    <div class="type__grid"> ...</div>
    <div class="type__grid"> ...</div>
    <div class="type__grid"> ...</div>
    <div class="type__grid"> ...</div>
    <div class="type__grid"> ...</div>
    <div class="type__grid"> ...</div>
    <h3 class="type__purpose-heading"> ... </h3>
    <div class="type__grid"> ...</div>
    <div class="type__grid"> ...</div>
    <div class="type__grid"> ...</div>
    <div class="type__grid"> ...</div>
    <div class="type__grid"> ...</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to set up nested dictionaries of the form

`h2 = {h3_1 : {h4_1: [li_1, ... li_n], h4_2: [li_1, ... li_n]}, h3_2: {...}}`

I am currently finding h2 and h3 but now I am having difficulties in looping through the div type_grid. Since the number of them is not fixed and html is not nested, I thought a good strategy would be to store in a list the tags of the main parent div, then store the index of the h3 tags and after use a while loop with the indicator and an if condition. This is very long, but I think it may work. I have two questions:

- how can I get *only* the list of tags given that `print(list(h2.parent.children))` is giving me the whole html structure in the code above? is this the way?
  `print([child.name for child in heading.parent.children])`
- Is there a better way to achieve this?

**Edit with my solution:**
it turns out there was a better way.. I accidentally printed a list of lists where the first element is the tag and the second is the text then I parsed them writing other functions in py:

```
children = heading.parent.children
allowed_tags = ["h2","h3","div","h4"]
list_h2_h3_d = [[child.name,child.text] for child in children if all([child.name in allowed_tags, len(child.text)>0])]
```

Comment: questions like "is this the way?" are not fit for this site, but it looks ok to me

Comment: Ok sorry, but I had more questions inside. I have found a solution that works. I leave it open as someone with a better idea may come